# Webpack file loader manipulate output path

Tags: webpack, gulp, copy, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

Let's say I have a simple loader, that's supposed to just move a file from source to deploy, i've just copied the rule alone for simplistic state.

```
{
    test: /\.cshtml$/,
    use : [{
        loader : 'file-loader',
        options :  {
            name : '[path][name].[ext]',  
            // context :'',
            // outputPath : ''  
        }
    }]
}
```

I've tried a million different combinations with this one, basically once the file-loader processes it, it copies it to the `output.path` in webpack config, the path is something like this:

`/outputpath/thenfilefromloader/to/folder/goes/here/nameoffile.cshtml`

What' I'm trying to do, is more or less, split the string after `goes` and concat with output path:

`/outputpath/goes/here/nameoffile.cshtml`

Is this even achievable? Basically I'm trying to get rid of gulp, these files were just copied with gulp and that's it, but the path was manipulated before it was copied.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are trying to do, replacing `[path]` placeholder with a defined path should do the work:

```
{
    test: /\.cshtml$/,
    use : [{
        loader : 'file-loader',
        options :  {
            name : 'goes/here/[name].[ext]',  
        }
    }]
}
```

You also might add a `hash` placeholder to avoid filename collisions:

```
name : 'goes/here/[name].[hash].[ext]',
```

Comment: Yes, but it would need to be dynamic for every file, there's a few rules based on their directory

Comment: The file-loader gives you quite a lot flexibility [filename templates](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#filename-templates). I've never tryed myself, but it should also accept a function since it uses [webpack's interpolateName loader-utils](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/blob/master/lib/interpolateName.js) under the hoods.